# System cannot find the path specified yiic command

Tags: windows, yii, cmd

Hi i have been trying last night about this error. The error comes when i am standing in a directory and i want to access a file yiic but error comes

> The System cannot find the path specified
>   My system:

1. Windows 8.1 64 bit
2. wamp server 3.0.06 64bit
3. PHP version 5.6.25(used by wamp server)
4. Yii 1.1.19

**My file strucure:**
C-->wamp64-->www->yii-->framework

**Problem:**
I am standing in framework folder. When i type this command to create a new yii project

```
C:\wamp64\www\yii\framework> yiic webapp C:\wamp64\www\testapp
```

I get this error

> The System cannot find the path specified

**Things I have tried so far:**

1. Ran cmd as administrator but same result
2. unlocked the yii zipped file, I have read that on some site that windows sometimes blocks .bat files in zipped file but same result

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following?

```
C:\wamp64\www\yii\framework> php yiic.php webapp C:\wamp64\www\testapp
```

You can find more details in an official docs:

> Note: When running yiic on Mac OS, Linux or Unix, you may need to
>   change the permission of the yiic file so that it is executable.
>   Alternatively, you may run the tool as follows,
>
> ```
> % cd WebRoot %
> php YiiRoot/framework/yiic.php webapp testdrive
> ```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/quickstart.first-app

Comment: official doc was the first document i read.but it did not work for me

Comment: @RafayZiaMir Have you added PHP to your PATH?

Comment: Yes. I added it.

Answer (score 0):

I just downloaded yii and there is no framework folder and I can't execute yiic